# Which class, part and state is used to draw selection?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, user-interface, visual-styles

I'm trying to draw selection/focus frame in my custom windows forms control using visual styles on Windows 7 with Aero enabled. I tried this one:

```
VisualStyleRenderer selectionRenderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.ListView.Item.Selected);
selectionRenderer.DrawBackground(g, visual.ItemArea);
```

And this one:

```
VisualStyleRenderer selectionRenderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.TreeView.Item.Selected);
selectionRenderer.DrawBackground(g, visual.ItemArea);
```

However, both fail with information, that neither TreeView.Item.Selected, nor ListView.Item.Selected is supported in current style. But hey, Windows draws the selection in the UI's treeviews:

[image: Selection in treeview]

And listviews:

[image: Selection in listview]

So which class and part should I use to draw the system selection rectangle?

---

**Edit:** I've tried to write the code in pure WinAPI. Here's a code fragment:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps); 

        HTHEME theme = OpenThemeData(hwnd, L"TREEVIEW");
        RECT rect;
        rect.left = 10;
        rect.top = 10;
        rect.right = 80;
        rect.bottom = 80;
        DrawThemeBackground(theme, hdc, TVP_TREEITEM, TREIS_SELECTED, &rect, &rect);
        CloseThemeData(theme);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps); 
        return 0L; 
    }
```

The result looks as following:

[image: Selection drawn in WinAPI]

Comment: for treeview have you setted FullRowSelect?

Comment: I'm drawing selection in my own control written from scratch. Are you refering to some VisualStyles options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was quite close. The full solution in pure WinAPI looks like this:

```
HWND mainWinHWND = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    L"MainWindowClass",
    L"WinAPI window",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    640,
    480,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);

if (!mainWinHWND)
    return -1;

SetWindowTheme(mainWinHWND, L"explorer", nullptr);
```

Then one may request OS to draw specific parts:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps); 

    HTHEME theme = OpenThemeData(hwnd, L"TREEVIEW");
    RECT rect;
    rect.left = 10;
    rect.top = 10;
    rect.right = 80;
    rect.bottom = 80;
    DrawThemeBackground(theme, hdc, TVP_TREEITEM, TREIS_SELECTED, &rect, &rect);
    CloseThemeData(theme);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps); 
    return 0L; 
}
```

Result:

[image]

It's a shame, that theming OS support is so poorly documented. For example, the `L"Explorer"` value is taken from MSDN's for SetWindowTheme, but there is no official list of parameters, which may be supplied to that routine.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN says that Visaul Styles are only supported on Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition and Windows Server 2003.

See the end of the **Remarks** section of this [this link (VisualStyleRenderer Class)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer.aspx), and **Remarks** section of [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleinformation.issupportedbyos.aspx). Also [`VisualStyleRenderer.IsSupported`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer.issupported.aspx) and [`VisualStyleInformation.IsSupportedByOS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleinformation.issupportedbyos.aspx) both return true, it seems that it is not supported on any OS other than XP and Server 2003!

Comment: This page says otherwise: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773187(v=vs.85).aspx ("Windows XP and later operating systems support a feature called visual styles that enables the appearance of common controls to change based on the theme chosen by the user.").